# How to assign filtered column data to a variable using Set in VBA excel?

Tags: vbscript, filter, microsoft-excel

I am newbie to VBA excel. I am trying to use **Set** to assign some data from a filtered column (through AutoFilter) to a variable (**X** in this case). Below shows the code and image of the table.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim X As Variant
    
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").AutoFilter _
                                     Field:=2, _
                                     Criteria1:="1"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set X = .Range("D3:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
   
End Sub
```

[image: 1]

The filtering works as I expected. However, I ended up setting the entire unfiltered data in the range of D3:D23 to *X*. How can I assign the filtered data from column D to **X**?